# SSRS recursive hierarchy expression to return the pre-determined value of the layer in the hierarchy

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have a SSRS report that uses a recursive hierarchy.  The bottom row shows the Store, the row above is the state, the row above is the country.  In the first data column, I've successfully calculated the Qty of sales on the state and country rows using the expression 
`=Sum(Fields!Vol_Current_Wk.Value).`

My problem however, is I need to include another column that returns a pre-defined measure.  The tricky part is the state and country results are already calculated, and is not based on a calculation I can replicate using the store level data.  I tried using the expression `=Fields!QTV_Wk.Value`, on the state and country rows, however this is not returning the correct results on these layers.

I can create 3 separate reports, one for store, state and country, and use the expression `=Fields!QTV_Wk.Value` to return the correct results, but the preference is keep as a grouped report to make it easier for the end user to read.  I'm hoping that a report that uses a recursive hierarchy grouping can have an expression that will return the value already pre-defined for each layer of the hierarchy.

Comment: While to above description is good, is it possible to elaborate on 'where' the other column with the pre-defined measure is coming from?  Could you link to an image uploaded to imgur perhaps?

Comment: You'll need to explain this a bit more e.g. what does =Fields!QTV_Wk.Value represent? Can you add an example of the source data (are the pre-calculated values returned in the same row as the lower level data or in a different dataset) and indicate what you mean by "not returning the correct results"?

Comment: Hi, the dataset I'm using comes from an Analysis Services MDX cube.  The =Fields!QTV_Wk.Value is a Measure that I'm picking up from this cube.

Comment: Apologies, I'm a first timer, and when I pressed enter, my comment above immediately posted.  The rest of my answer is:  When I drag the measure into the dataset, it already has the pre-calculated results from the MDX cube for the store, state and country level.  When I group, then the state and Country levels only return the result of the store that's directly underneath it, not the result for the state or region.  I can't see an option for me to load a screenshot of the cube showing the measure.....